# How can I figure the number of trials until success?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, statistics

I have a player who I want to let make many attempts at the same skill check. (I'm aware [that's not always the best way to do it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49239/23970), but it makes sense in some cases.) But rather than rolling many times until success, I'd like a single roll to tell me the number of attempts--and therefore the in-game time--it could take my player's character to succeed.

I'm aware that the *expected* time to success, given each individual trial's chance of success \$p\$, is given by \$\overline{T}=\frac{1}{p}\$. ([See also.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Introduction_to_the_geometric_distribution)) But I want something that could give different outcomes, simulating the results of iterated skill checks.

**How can I simulate iterated skill checks with one die roll?**

---

This question motivated by the comment-colloquy [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/how-many-times-may-a-character-attempt-a-skill-roll-for-the-same-test/84884#comment201160_84885), reproduced below for posterity:

> A: I'm talking probability of 1 trial to success (= P obviously), probability at most 2 trials to success, at most 3, etc... And in turn, a way to turn a single roll (representing how good your result is in the relevant probability space) into "how many actual trials to success".
>
> B: Ah, so are you talking something like taking p=0.5 you'd generate a percentile table: 01-50=>1, 51-75=>2, 76-87=>3, &c.? So that one percentile roll would give a properly distributed number of trials to success *in this instance?*
>
> A: yeah

Answer (score 19):

**You want a table that models "stacked" probabilities.**

For example, if the chance of any individual attempt's success is 40%, your table might look like this:

\begin{array}{cc}
n\text{ to success} & \text{d}100\text{ roll}\\ \hline
1 & 01-40\\
2 & 41-64\\
3 & 65-78\\
4 & 79-87\\
5 & 88-92\\
6 & 93-95\\
7 & 96-97\\
8 & 98\\
9 & 99\\
10 & 100\\
\end{array}

But how do you generate this table?

---

Given the probability \$p\$ of succeeding on any given attempt, then the probability of succeeding ***on*** the \$n^\text{th}\$ attempt is given by $$P(n)=(1-p)^{n-1}\cdot p$$

This is because in order to succeed on the \$n^\text{th}\$ attempt we must first *fail*, with a probability \$(1-p)\$, \$n-1\$ times, *then* succeed (with probability \$p\$).

Thus in the example above we see that 
\begin{align*}
P(1)&=p=0.4\\
P(2)&=(1-p)\cdot p =0.24\\
P(3)&=(1-p)^2\cdot p \approx0.14\\
P(4)&=(1-p)^3\cdot p \approx 0.09\\
\vdots\quad& \hspace{2cm}\vdots
\end{align*}

But in order to *stack* the probabilities we recognize that the "break points"--the highest number in each of the percentile ranges--are given by the *sum* of all probabilities up to the \$n^\text{th}\$.
Luckily, this is just a geometric series: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{(1-p)^i} = \frac{1-(1-p)^n}{p}$$

With this in hand it's easy to generate a table of "break points" for any given \$p\$:

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
& \text{d}100\text{ roll}\\
n\text{ to success} & p=0.1 & p=0.2 & p=0.3 & p=0.4 & p=0.5 &p=0.6 &p=0.7\\ \hline
1 & 01-10 & 01-20 & 01-30 & 01-40 & 01-50 & 01-60 & 01-70\\
2 & 11-19 & 21-36 & 31-51 & 41-64 & 51-75 & 61-84 & 71-91\\
3 & 20-27 & 37-49 & 52-66 & 65-78 & 76-88 & 85-94 & 92-97\\
4 & 28-34 & 50-59 & 67-76 & 79-87 & 89-94 & 95-97 & 98-99\\ \hline
5 & 35-41 & 60-67 & 77-83 & 88-92 & 95-97 & 98-99 & 100\\
6 & 42-47 & 68-74 & 84-88 & 93-95 & 98 & 100\\
7 & 48-52 & 75-79 & 89-92 & 97-97 & 99\\
8 & 53-57 & 80-83 & 93-94 & 98 & 100\\\hline
9 & 58-61 & 84-87 & 95-96 & 99 & \\
10 & 62-65 & 88-89 & 97 & 99 & \\
11 & 66-69 & 90-91 & 98 & 100 & \\
12 & 70-72 & 92-93 & 99 &  & \\\hline
13 & 73-75 & 94-95 & 99 &  & \\
14 & 76-77 & 96 & 99 &  & \\
15 & 78-79 & 96 & 100 &  & \\
16 & 80-81 & 97 &  &  & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\end{array}

**Notes:**

<sup>1. In a few places the same single number appears twice. (*p*=0.2, *n*=14,15, for instance.) In these cases multiple break-points round to the same percent-value. You could randomly choose from among *n* values if this is rolled, simply take the lower, or devise some other scheme.</sup>

<sup>2. Obviously, there is a non-zero probability that success would take longer than I've indicated, ending my tables at the first appearance of a rounded-to-100 percent-value. However, by construction there is less than a 1/2% chance that *any* *n* greater than the last presented could occur. I felt fine leaving the long tail off the table.</sup>

Comment: Interesting table. I don't think there is any other way of doing what you want whilst staying true to the exact mechanics you want to simulate. If you consider the relative ease of rolling a die repeatedly, vs accessing the pre-computed table then using it, then you can determine whether this approach is worth the effort. For low p values it might be. My cut-off to "just roll many times" is probably around p>=0.3 (given that 9 times out of 10, we'd roll less than 8 times).

Comment: It's the sort of thing I could see being useful to a GM who plays with a laptop to hand. It's super-easy to code this into a spreadsheet and just input the p-value up top, watching the whole column update. Or, if you're *really* into creating situations where unchanging repetition happens and time *really* matters, maybe you print a table like this and tape it to your screen.

Comment: @nitsua60 As a GM who religiously uses his laptop at the gaming table for character sheets, bookmarked PDF documents, checking online system reference documents for obscure rules/details, and using random generators, I could definitely see myself incorporating this into a spreadsheet just as you describe.

Answer (score 8):

### Roll 3d(\$3\overline{T}\$), take the lowest.

As you say, the *expected* time to success, given the probability of any individual trial succeeding is \$p\$, is given by \$\overline{T}=\frac{1}{p}\$.

If you figure that expected time-to-success, triple it, roll three of *that* die-size, and take the lowest, you'll get a very good approximation of the right distribution.

For example, suppose you have a +5 modifier and encounter a DC20 challenge:

1. You then have a 30% chance of success (\$p=0.3\$);
2. \$\overline{T}=\frac{1}{p}=3 \frac{1}{3}\$;
3. \$3\overline{T}=10\$, so d10 are our needed dice;
4. roll 3d10, take the lowest.

Below are pictured comparisons for various \$p\$ values. The exact values are the probability of each *n* being the successful trial, calculated as in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/92491/23970). The approximate values are those obtained through [anydice simulation](http://anydice.com/program/a415) of the roll-three-take-lowest method. *[Click for larger image]*

[image: p=0.1]
[image: p=0.2]
[image: p=0.3]
[image: p=0.5]

Obviously this method assumes you're pretty happy doing some mental math: figuring the expected time to success, then probably simulating some off-sided dice with standard die rolls.