# Is there a specified length of time that a pc must wait before trying to perform the same action (due to a previously failed ability check)

Tags: dnd-5e, difficulty-class

For example, a rogue fails a roll attempting to unlock a prison cell.  All other pc party members fail on their respective rolls.  At that point, may the initial rogue try again or are the prisoners in the cells just stuck there?

Comment: related: [how many times a check can be attempted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84883/23970), [I failed to open a lock, now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49239/23970)

Comment: From what I can gather from answers to similar questions here is that there is not a specific length of time to wait and that there are several potential ways that this can be handled

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92490/23970 might also be of interest.